# Rails doesn't migrate one table out of 3 in production mode, runs fine in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, production-environment

I have three tables: Project, Tasks, and Tags. When migrate the databases in development mode, everything works.

But when I run the rake db schema load command for production mode, it isn't migrating the "Tasks" table, hence the app doesn't work.

I looked at my production.log file, but there isn't anything there.

What am I missing here?

You can fork it over from github if you prefer: http://github.com/senthilnambi/MultipleM

I'm using sqlite3, btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a quick look in your schema.rb file and can see this line:

```
# Could not dump table "tasks" because of following StandardError
# Unknown type 'body' for column 'reason'
```

Looks like you need to recreate your schema file from the migrations to remove this error.

Comment: You're right, I accidentally had ":body" as type for one of the columns. But, I corrected it and it still gives me the same error. How do I "recreate" my schema file? Thanks for your help

Comment: rake db:schema:dump should update your db/schema.rb file to match the structure of your database. Add RAILS_ENV=staging or whatever if you need to specify the environment.